# How do I push a commit to a git repository through curl?

Tags: git, http, curl

I know how to add files to a git repository using the `git` command. But I'm trying to reinvent the wheel and I want to add a file to a git repository only using `curl` to connect to the server. So far, what I've done is create a dummy repository, Wireshark the push request, and copy the data. This gives me a `pack` file that I can send to the server. But when I run

```
curl <my server>/git-receive-pack -H "Content-Type: application/x-git-receive-pack-request" -d "@raw_pack"
```

nothing happens. No file is created. (`raw_pack` contains the entire data of the packet from Wireshark). I removed the file before running this so it 100% doesn't exist. I read the entirety of the technical documentation on Git http protocol and pack protocol but I still can't figure this out. How do I push a commit to a git repository with only curl? (Ideally only POST requests).

Comment: Git repositories do not have “files”. They have _commits_.

Comment: ok. then how do I add a commit to a repository with only curl?

Comment: There is more than one push protocol, but the usual one is full of negotiations: you send stuff to them, they send stuff to you, and both of you act on the data you get from each other. In general, you cannot just have a prepackaged blob of data that you send. The only way that would work is if you know in advance what they will send to *you*, and you can't know that.

Comment: i'm sending data to git-recieve pack, so the only data that it sends back is confirmation